Is it possible to build opencv statically under Linux without having problems with missing/incompatible libraries?
I'm trying to distribute an opencv binary on different Linux operating systems, but I've failed because of dependency problems.
What I'm aiming for is something similar to the opencv-python pip package that doesn't require additional software to be installed.
My questions are as follows:

Is it possible to build opencv statically under Linux without having problems with missing/incompatible libraries?
If so, can you show me how?
If not, how did the opencv-python team succeed in doing this?
opencv-python uses Qt.
I looked at the project and couldn't find a clue.

OpenCV were built statically.
I first had a problem with glibc version incompatibility. An update on the different systems solved the problem.
Then I had a missing libtiff.so error. set(BUILD_TIFF ON) solved the problem.
Then I got an error that libQtWidgets.so was missing.
I installed the qtbase5-dev package. However, I don't want users to have to install new software.
I tried to build qtbase statically, but it complained that the opengl library was missing.
This means that the static library will still require opengl to be installed on the destination machines.
Which again is incompatible with my goal.
Even after installing qtbase5-dev, I had another version incompatibility with libavcodec.
Update 1
Looking at cv2.abi3.so gave more information.
readelf -d cv2.abi3.so shows
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/../opencv_python.libs]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpng16-7379b3c3.so.16.40.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libavcodec-512f0acb.so.59.37.100]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libavformat-3ff1be5b.so.59.27.100]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libavutil-a0a0531e.so.57.28.100]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libswscale-2c3c8be7.so.6.7.100]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Widgets-e69d94fb.so.5.15.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Gui-a7aedf18.so.5.15.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Test-c38a5234.so.5.15.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Core-39545cc7.so.5.15.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopenblas-r0-f650aae0.3.3.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]

Some of the dependencies names have been rewritten and shipped with the package in the opencv_python.libs directory.
I intend to do the same.
The renaming process seems to be part of the packaging process.
Numpy has similiar renamings, making me think that the renaming process is outside python-opencv
I am still looking for that renaming process

is it enough to use  apt -q update -y && apt -q install -y build-essential libopencv-dev ?

Have you considered using docker?

opencv-python does not usually come with Qt. if it does, that is either obtained as a dependency on another python package, or shipped/included as a DLL/SO somewhere in lib/site-packages/cv2

@Ivan That is not possible because it is a custom opencv build

@MarkSetchell, well a library cannot be distributed as a docker image. It is like wanting to put a python pip package in docker

@ChristophRackwitz I doubt that, on Ubuntu and Linux Mint, opencv-python gui shows buttons that are created by modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp#void CvWindow::createActions();
More over, looking at https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/blob/4.x/setup.py#L234
it is built with Qt5

@ChristophRackwitz and sudo apt list --installed | grep qt is empty

The OpenGL library is more or less always available in a standard Linux installation (as it is on Windows and macOS). If your program needs to run on some minimalist Linux installation, then don’t build the OpenCV components that need functionality not available on the target system. You can disable the highgui component, which removes dependencies on graphics display. Disable all of the image file formats that your application won’t use. Etc.

I found a solution.
opencv-python uses auditwheel to relabel cross-distribution Linux wheels.
There is a workaround to relabel any shared libraries.
If maximum portability is needed, use some of the manylinux images as a build hosts. I have used the image opencv-python-manylinux2014-x86-64.
Install python and needed packages
python -m pip install build auditwheel

[Optional] Exclude shared libraries we don't want to relabel
Execute the follwing pyton script
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
import json

from auditwheel import policy

def patch_whitelisted_libs():
    policies = None

    with open(join(dirname(abspath(policy.__file__)), "manylinux-policy.json")) as f:
        policies = json.load(f)

    lib_whitelist = [
        "libxcb.so.1",
    ]

    lib_blacklist = []

    changed = False

    for p in policies:
        for lib in lib_whitelist:
            if not (lib in p["lib_whitelist"]):
                p["lib_whitelist"].append(lib)
                changed = True

        for lib in lib_blacklist:
            if lib in p["lib_whitelist"]:
                p["lib_whitelist"].remove(lib)
                changed = True

    if changed:
        with open(join(dirname(abspath(policy.__file__)), "manylinux-policy.json"), "w") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(policies))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    patch_whitelisted_libs()


Create a python project specifying your distributed shared libraries
setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

ext_module = Extension('package_name', sources = [], libraries = [])

setup(
    name='package_name',
    version = '0.0.0',
    packages = ['package_name'],
    package_dir = {'package_name': '/path/to/shared_objects/directory'},
    package_data = {'package_name': ['opencv_custom.so', 'qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so']},
    ext_modules = [ext_module],
)

pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=58"
]

build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

Build the python project
python -m build --wheel

Relabel the shared objects
python -m auditwheel repair dist/<generated built wheel>

Extract the relabelled shared objects
unzip -o -d relabelled dist/<generated built wheel> 'package_name/*' 'package_name.libs/*'

[Optional] change rpath to suit your distribution tree layout
auditwhell expects you to keep the tree layout extracted. If it is not the case, change the rpath of every shared object defined by package_data in the setup.py file with
patchelf --force-rpath --set-rpath '$ORIGIN/<you tree layout>' <your shared object>

QT plugins and fonts problem
QT may complain about not being able to load a plugin. I solved it by setting an environment variable
QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/path/to/the/distributed/plugins

QT may complain about not founding fonts. I solved it by setting an environment variable
QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/path/to/the/distributed/fonts/dejavu

